# Join two function with a cubic polynomial function

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

**Background :** I am new in Dynamic Simulation and I would like to understand how the researchers smoothen the equation between $4.5 Å$ and $6 Å$. The equation is the [Lennard Jones Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) and $\varepsilon$ and $\sigma$ can be taken as constants.

[image]

*[Taken from [here]](https://daslab.stanford.edu/site_data/pub_pdf/2017_Alford_JCTC.pdf)*

Answer (score 0):

A cubic polynomial has 4 coefficients: $y= ax^3+ bx^2+ cx+ d$.  That means that you can choose those coefficients to match 4 conditions.  In particular you can chose the coefficients so that the values of y and y' are correct at the two endpoints.